# android andengine remove physics body crash application

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics, physics-engine

I am writing a game in which i have to remove a rectangular brick with body on collision. The error occurs on ***_physicsWorld.destroyBody(b);***

Here is my code snippet and logcat output (logcat says there is error in *libc*):

**Code**:

```
public void destroyBrick(IShape s, Body b, int i){

    PhysicsConnector facePhysicsConnector = _physicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(s);

        _physicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(facePhysicsConnector);

    _scene.unregisterTouchArea(s);

    _scene.detachChild(s);

    _physicsWorld.destroyBody(b);

    System.gc();

}
```

**Logcat**:

```
***08-19 12:58:17.491: A/libc(29832): /home/denbi/src/android/AndEngineExtensions/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtensionNew/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp:134: void b2World::DestroyBody(b2Body*): assertion "IsLocked() == false" failed
08-19 12:58:17.501: A/libc(29832): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 29852 (UpdateThread)***
```

please help me out asap.
thanks

Comment: @Jithesh.. Could to get the answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove bodies during the execution of `b2World::Step`. You have to store the list of bodies you want to remove and actually remove them when Step exits.

Example (C++):

```
//in contact handling:
m_bodiesToRemove.push_back(my_body);

//after Step:
for (b2Body *b : m_bodiesToRemove):
    m_world->DestroyBody(b);
```

Comment: got d solution, i implemented IUpdateHandler and inside that i run my delete method.